# RecordBTN.enabled == false swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

```
 //result of call to '==' is unused
```

What does that mean and how can i fix it?

```
RecordBTN.enabled == false
```

The compiler is telling me type of expression is ambiguous without more content.

```
 var recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue, AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2, AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your statement `RecordBTN.enabled == false`, you are comparing `RecordBTN.enabled` to `false`, but you aren't doing anything with the result of the comparison (a Boolean value). You may want to store the result in a variable or use it in an `if` statement..

If you are trying to set `RecordBTN.enabled` to `false`, use the assignment operator (a single'='):

```
RecordBTN.enabled = false
```

The operators are [well documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html).